# Update WPF Datagrid when item is added to ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I can not figure this out to save my life.

I have a simple WPF form where I enter data in a text box, the user can click insert and it saves to the database.  I also have a datagrid that is showing all the values.

I can NOT get the datagrid to "refresh" with the full list of values after the new item is inserted.  I have googled and searched for days but I just can not figure out what line I am missing to communicate back to the UI to refresh the grid view.

Please help me, for the love of God, please someone help me out of this NOOB nightmare

This is my ViewModel

```
    public partial class CatView : ObservableObject
    {
        private List<Category> _Cats = Category.all.Values.ToList();
        

        public List<Category> Cats 
        {
            get { return _Cats; }
            set
            { 
                _Cats = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Cats");                
            }
        }
}
```

WPF Form XAML

```
`<Window x:Class="Recycle4Core.CategoryEdit"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Recycle4Core.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Category Editor" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:CatView />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <!--<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>-->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="InputStack"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <Grid x:Name="GridPanelNameInput">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="FirstColumn" />
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SecondColumn" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="Category Name" 
                       Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                <TextBox x:Name="txtINPUT" 
                         Text="{Binding SelectedCategory.name}" 
                         Height="20" 
                         Width="150" 
                         Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="ButtonGrid">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="FirstColumn" />
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SecondColumn"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ThirdColumn"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button x:Name="btnInsert"
                    Height="20"
                    Width="100"
                    Content="Insert"
                    Margin="20 10 0 0" 
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Click="btnInsert_Click"
                    />
                <Button x:Name="btnUpdate"
                    Height="20"
                    Width="100"
                    Content="Update"
                    Margin="20 10 0 0" 
                    Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnDelete"
                    Height="20"
                    Width="100"
                    Content="Delete"
                    Margin="20 10 0 0" 
                    Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>

            <Button x:Name="btnExit"
                    Height="40"
                    Width="150"
                    Content="EXIT"
                    Margin="0 30 0 0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    />

        </StackPanel>

        <!--<DataGrid x:Name="grdCategory" 
                  Grid.Column="1" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}"
                  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>-->

        <DataGrid x:Name="grdCategory" 
                  Grid.Column="1" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"

            >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>`
```

WPF Form Code

```
`        private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
`        {
            string newName = txtINPUT.Text.ToString();
            Category test = Category.get(newName);
            if (test != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This Category Already Exists, Item was not Saved", "ERROR", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return;
            }
            if (txtINPUT.Text.ToString() != null )
            {

                List<Category> categoryData = new List<Category>();
                Category cat = new Category(txtINPUT.Text);
                categoryData.Add(cat);
                Category.add(cat);

                Category.Raw cats = new Category.Raw(categoryData);
                CategoryDAO.categoriesInsert(cats);
                grdCategory.Items.Refresh();
                
                CategoryDAO.loadData();
            }
        }
``
```

I have tried using ObservableCollection instead of List<>.  I have tried various attributes from the MVVM toolkit.  I have read and searched and read and searched.  I just can not figure this out.  I know it's some stupid simple thing and it's driving me crazy because I can't make any progress on the actual value of my application cause I'm spinning my wheels on this nonsense

Comment: do you have to use MVVM toolkit? I Can give you a simple answer without any toolkit

Comment: I don't have to use the MVVM toolkit.  It just seemed like that may make things easier so I was starting with it.  I really don't care how I get it to work at this point, I just want it to work ;-)

Comment: ok. first of all you didn't follow MVVM pattern in your code. it's ok but if you want to fully apply this pattern you should define elements like Command and ViewModelBase. so, you didn't add category so I'll make something up.

Comment: where is the simple answer?  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to learn WPF you shouldn't think of it as windows form. there are many good tutorials which starts from basic concepts.
And I didn't find ***Categories*** *property* which you bound to DataGrid as Item Source. is there somthing missing your code?

but until then

1.you ***ViewModel*** Class ( which appear to be a window) should implement ***INotifyPropertyChange*** interface. so it can communicate with view.something like this:

```
public partial class CatView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Category> _Cats = Category.all.Values.ToList();

    public ObservableCollection<Category> Cats
    {
        get { return _Cats; }
        set
        {
            _Cats = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


 private string _InputText;
 public string InputText
        {
            get { return _InputText; }
            set { _InputText= value; OnPropertyChanged(this); }

        }

    public ICommand AddCommand { get; set; }

    public CatView()
    {
         AddCommand = new RelayCommand(Add);
    }

     private void Add(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"{InputText}");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

as you can see

- I used ***ObservableCollection*** instead of List.

2.the following is an example of RelayCommand implementation:

```
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
        {
            private readonly Action<object> execute;
    
            private readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;
    
            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
            {
                add
                {
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
                }
                remove
                {
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
                }
            }
    
       public RelayCommand(Action execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
            {
                if (execute == null)
                {
                    throw new System.ArgumentNullException("execute");
                }
    
                this.execute = delegate
                {
                    execute();
                };
                this.canExecute = canExecute;
            }
      public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
            {
                this.execute = execute ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException("execute");
                this.canExecute = canExecute;
            }
      public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                if (canExecute != null)
                {
                    return canExecute(parameter);
                }
    
                return true;
            }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                execute(parameter);
            }
    }
```

**Update:**
I add InputText property which you could bind to your textbox text attribute like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding InputText}" />
```

Comment: I implemented your code block, but I don't understand how the Add method is supposed to get the text that I entered into the textbox.

Comment: I tried to bind one of the buttons to the AddCommand you created as follows

Comment: <Button x:Name="btnUpdate"
                    Height="20"
                    Width="100"
                    Content="Update"
                    Margin="20 10 0 0" 
                    Grid.Column="1"
                       Command="{Binding AddCommand}" 
                        />

Comment: now I would expect the code to do something when I click the update button, but nothing happens.  I put a stop inside the Add method and it never gets triggered.

Comment: @ShaneIsStuck if you want to have anything in view communicate to code you should bind properies. I will add a property of textbox to the example

Comment: I have Update the answer with a property for textbox binding. I will add comment on code to explain how every part works.